# Map list of strings to a array of TextEditingControllers

Tags: flutter

I have a list of `textFormfields` in a slider and I'm getting a list of data from the api which contains a description. I need to map that descriptions to the `TextEditingControllers` to show them on the `textFormfield`, Can someone please give me a solution for this?

Example:  `List<TextEditingController> _controllers = [];`

```
"data": [
{
    "id": 1,
    "value": "Title 1",
    "description": "description 1",
    "userId": 1,
                
},{
    "id": 2,
    "value": "Title 2",
    "description": "description 2",
    "userId": 2,
                
},{
    "id": 3,
    "value": "Title 3",
    "description": "description 3",
    "userId": 3,
},],
```

[This is how I did](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJEZX.png)

comment value seems to be swapping when I'm sliding

Answer (score 0):

First of All create `Model` of your `response` like below

```
class MyModelData {

  int? id;
  String? value;
  TextEditingController? description = TextEditingController();
  int? userId;

  MyModelData({
    this.id,
    this.value,
    this.description,
    this.userId,
  });
  MyModelData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id']?.toInt();
    value = json['value']?.toString();
    description = json['description'];
    userId = json['userId']?.toInt();
  }
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final data = <String, dynamic>{};
    data['id'] = id;
    data['value'] = value;
    data['description'] = description;
    data['userId'] = userId;
    return data;
  }
}
```

then create list like this

```
List<MyModelData> dataList = <MyModelData>[];
```

below `list?.forEach` is the list for data that you are getting from `API's response`

```
list?.forEach((element) {
         dataList.add(RoomDimensionModel(
            id: element.id,
            value: element.id,
            description: TextEditingController(element.description),
            userId: element.userId,
          ));
        });
```

then use `dataList` every where you would like to use in `UI`.

Comment: I have mapped the controller text value like this.But when I swipe the slider the values seems to be swapping.im.ge/i/FYgzq8 here's the code

Comment: you are not following as per what i said.

Comment: I need the description as a string too thats why I can't create the model like you mentioned.I need to assign the description to the controller.text value of the controller list.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you parsed the response successfully. What you need is to use the map function provided for dart lists:

```
List<String> descriptions = dataList.map((e) => e.description).toList();
          print(descriptions);
```

And then just use a loop to assign these descriptions to the TextControllers list:

```
for (var i = 0; i < controllersList.length; ++i) {
            var textController = controllersList[i];
            var desc = descriptions[i];
            textController.text = desc;
          }
```

of course the textControllers list is as the same length as the descriptions list.

Comment: I have mapped the controller text value like this.But when I swipe the slider the values seems to be swapping.https://im.ge/i/FYgzq8 here's the code